# How to detect user is scrolling the div content when scrollTop is 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with some elements with `overflow-y: scroll` property. Now, I have written jQuery code for `scroll` event. It works fine when I scroll the content. But when the `scrollTop` is **0**, it doesn't work as `scroll` event works only when you're really scrolling. The scroll stops when the top is 0.

So is there any way to detect user is still scrolling after `scrollTop` is set to 0?

```
$("#nbody").on("scroll", function(){
       if(this.scrollTop === 0) {
         //this works only when scrollTop changes from 0+n value.
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a few options:

1. Use the onWheel callback (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onwheel.asp). This does not work on Safari and IE <= 8
2. Look for a third party library that emulates this
3. Use a hidden div and some CSS to catch all scrolling there. It will take you some tinkering. You can use javascript to set the scrollTop of the div to something > 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try below code:**
**For Bottom :**

```js
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $('#nbody').bind('scroll', function()
                              {
                                if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
                                {
                                  alert('end reached');
                                }
                              })
  }
);
```

```css
#nbody{width:200px;height:150px;overflow:auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nbody">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br>
Consectetuer augue nibh lacus at <br>
Pretium Donec felis dolor penatibus <br>
Phasellus consequat Vivamus dui lacinia <br>
Ornare nonummy laoreet lacus Donec <br>
Ut ut libero Curabitur id <br>
Dui pretium hendrerit sapien Pellentesque <br>

</div>
```

**For Top:**

```js
var el = $('.test');



el.on('scroll', function(){
    
    if(el.scrollTop() == 0){alert("hit the top")}
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" style="height:100px;width:70px;overflow:auto">
    sadfsadf
    saf
    sadf
    saf
    s
    af
    saf
    saf
    sadf
    sadfsafsafsaf
    sadfsaf
    
    sadfsafsadf
    
    sadfsaf
    sa
    dfsa
    fsadf
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this solves nothing… OP wants to detect the scrolling when user comes back to the top of the div.

Comment: @Philicare I changed my answer please check and let me know.Thanks

Comment: You solve just a too easy problem, @Ashish. OP wants negative values, when user reach the top (from bottom to top for instance), then still scroll  (don't ask me why, I don't know).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by additional way like get scroll delay of user experience 
actually in my code it set to 250, but you can replace how you prefer

```
$(".someDiv").scroll(function() {
var th = this;
var scrollDelay = 250;
clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));

$.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
    // do something
    if (th.scrollTop === 0) {
            //this works only when scrollTop changes from 0+n value.
        console.log(555);
        }
}, scrollDelay));
});
```

[see example](http://jsfiddle.net/v7v2uxpq/)